How does the first hitting time depend on the drift of drifted Brownian motion?
Let $W$ be a standard Brownian motion, and $a,b:\mathbb R_+\times \mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ be Lipschitz. Consider the stochastic differential equations:
$$X_t=1+\int_0^ta(s,X_s)ds + W_t,\quad\quad Y_t=1+\int_0^tb(s,Y_s)ds + W_t.$$
Fix some $T>0$ and set $\epsilon:=\|a-b\|:=\sup_{(t,x)\in [0,T]\times \mathbb R} |a(t,x)-b(t,x)|$. Denote by $\tau,\sigma$ the first hitting times of $X,Y$ at zero. What is the related literature for the estimation
$$\mathbb P[\tau\le t<\sigma]\le k(\epsilon),\quad \forall t\in [0,T]?$$
Here $k: \mathbb R_+ \to [0,1]$ is some continuous function vanishing at zero, e.g. $k(\epsilon)=C\epsilon^\alpha$ for some $C>0$ and $\alpha\in (0,1]$.

An idea - use Gronwall as usual to bound the expected sup norm of $X - Y$ in terms of $\epsilon$, then Markov for a bound in probability, which translates to the desired bound on the probability in question.

@NateRiver Thanks for the comment. The "difference" between X and Y is straightforward, using classical arguments. However, the hitting time is not continuous with respect to the uniform norm. I don't see how the desired probability follows from the estimation of $X-Y$

It is not continuous but it should be “continuous in probability”. The reasoning is that if $X$ hits zero at time $t$, with large probability it hits $-\varepsilon$ before time $t + \delta(\varepsilon)$, and so $Y$ hits zero sometime before $t + \delta(\varepsilon)$. An analysis of $\delta$ should give the form of $k$.

Ah of course, it seems $\delta$ can be chosen to be of order $\varepsilon^2$.

Shall we continue in private chat? I will see if I can explain it informally to you. If it is still not clear, then I can write up the details as an answer here.

@NateRiver Of course, while I don't know how to turn into private chat... I see what you mean, if $a,b$ are constants such as $c, c+\epsilon$, explicit computation helps. For general functions, how can we achieve this?

@NateRiver I do appreciate if you can write down an answer

Hi, have you managed to figure this out yet? I think you can use this linearization result to show the conclusion you want. If you can't figure it out, I'll write a full answer here, free of charge. Let me know if you're interested.
